How to use intel TCO watchdog with iTCO_wdt?
I have an intel platform (Alder Lake N50) and I'm trying to use the chipset watchdog hardware.
My kernel is configured to have the iTCO_wdt module, when I insert it, the device is detected and /dev/watchdog is created:
TCO_wdt iTCO_wdt: Found a Intel PCH TCO device (Version=6, TCOBASE=0x0400)
iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=120 sec (nowayout=0)

However, no process pings /dev/watchdog (checked with lsof), and the system never reboots.
I tried: cat >> /dev/watchdog and every time I get the message: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop! and the system does not reboot.
I've also noticed this message every time I reboot my system:
watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
systemd-shutdown[1]: Using hardware watchdog 'iTCO_wdt', version 0, device /dev/watchdog0
systemd-shutdown[1]: Watchdog running with a timeout of 10min.

Where do these '10min' come from? And how can I update it and kill the process that refresh the watchdog to test if the system reboot?

Do you have WDAT table on /sys/firmware/acpi/tables?

No, i also recompiled my kernel with CONFIG_WDAT_WDT, but no WDAT table on /sys/firmware/acpi/tables

Have you tried wdctl /dev/watchdog or wdctl /dev/watchdog1 as root ?

Look at man 5 system.conf.d: "By default RuntimeWatchdogSec= defaults to 0 (off), and RebootWatchdogSec= to 10min." I.e. by default watchdog timeout is not configured for normal operation, and is configured to 10 min for reboot stage.
